# Does a linear function $\mathrm {End}_K(V) \otimes V \to V$ which maps $A \otimes v$ to $\det (A) \cdot v$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

$K$ is a field and $V$ a finite dimensional $K$-vector space.

Does a linear function $\mathrm {End}_K(V) \otimes V \to V$ which maps $A \otimes v$ to $\det (A) \cdot v$, for all $A \in \mathrm {End}_K(V)$ and all $v \in V$ exist?

Comment: What have you tried in between posting these questions?

Comment: Is it right to say you’re looking for a function $f$ taking two arguments - a matrix and a vector - with the desired property? What does it mean for this function to be linear, since it would take two arguments?

Comment: @paulinho A linear function out of a tensor product $A\otimes V$ is the same as a function of $A\times V$ which is bilinear, i.e. linear in $A$ or $V$ while the other argument is held constant. This is standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If such a map exists the map ${\rm End}_K(V)\times V\to V$ given by $(A,v)\to\det(A)\cdot v$ should be **bilinear**, which is not the case, because, $\det$ is not linear, that is $\det(A+B)\neq\det(A)+\det(B)$ and $\det(cA)\neq c\det(A)$ in general, and if $\dim_KV>1$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, such map does not exists. Suppose a linear map $\psi : \operatorname{End}_K(V) \otimes V \rightarrow V$  satisfiying the condition. Then $\psi((cA)\otimes v )=\det(cA)v=c^n\det(A)v$ whereas $c \psi(A \otimes v)= c\det(A)v$, where $n=\dim_K V$. This is absurd.